# iPhone icon design - what are the resolutions?

Tags: iphone

What are the resolutions for icons on the iPhone? Are they 72ppi or 163ppi for the new iPhone?

Comment: this one's for you: http://farm1.staticflickr.com/4/7942538_48903e3585.jpg

Answer (score 2):

For iPhone it is 57x57 pixels, and 114x114 pixels to support iOS4 retina displays. 
See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Answer (score 0):

See this GitHub repo, it contains all the icons and sizes you need:

https://github.com/FattusMannus/iOS-Development-Image-Placeholders